# "imported and not used" error, but package is needed, just not called in code

Tags: validation, go, import

I'm using the [validator2](https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v2) library to validate struct fields in my Go application. The result looks something like this:

```
type data struct {
    Event string `json:"event" validate:"nonzero"`
}
```

However, when I try importing the library with

```
import ( 
    "gopkg.in/validator.v2"
)
```

it returns an error, `imported and not used: "flight-recorder/vendor/gopkg.in/validator.v2" as validator`. This is because the library isn't directly called in the code. How can I indicate that to Go?

Comment: How are you using that package? It has no init function, so there are no side effects to importing it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to import this package? As far as I can see, that's not needed?

Answer (score 8):

To import a library only for its side effects (i.e. to run a package `init` function), use an empty import:

```
import ( 
    _ "gopkg.in/validator.v2"
)
```

**However, this package does *not* have a package `init` function, so there is no point in importing it.** You do not need to import a package just to use the struct tags - struct tags are arbitrary and not compile-time checked, nor do they have to be defined before use. They're purely for use in reflection.